# Console always in orange when I run a script with a deprecated Python

Tags: python

I'm running a simple program to check what modules I have installed with pip, that's my example code:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

packages = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip',
                                            'list', '--format', 'json'])
                                            
print("HELLO")
```

I'm running it with a deprecated Python version (2.7 exactly), so that I get a warning orange message in the console.

My problem is that everything I display on the cmd after that is always orange (unless I say it exlpicitly with colorama for every line)

Is there a way to change the whole output to be white again after getting that warning message?

Comment: Forgive me for stating what might be obvious to you, but an easy way would be to upgrade to a non-deprecated Python (a good idea for many reasons aside from your terminal coloring issue).

Comment: add `print("\033[0m")` at the end. It should reset back to default colors

Comment: Yes, well that's a solution, but that's something for a whole project (and a bunch of dependencies) that is running with that deprecated version of Python, it is not feasible to change the version right now

Comment: Hi @Plopp, I already tried it but the orange colour reamins